# Error when compiling file in c

Tags: c, file, compiler-errors

I keep getting this as an error when trying to compile. Whats causing this error? and how can i fix it?

fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x390

```
#ifndef DEFS_H
#define DEFS_H


// a structure that contains field widths
typedef struct {
    int * fieldWidths; // a pointer to an array of bit field widths (in bits)
    int numWidths;     // the number of elements in the array (i.e., the number of bit    fields)
} sizes;


// a structure that contains an array of ints containing packed data fields
typedef struct {
    int * fieldValues; // a pointer to an array of ints containing packed bit fields
    int n;             // the number of elements in the array
} packed;


// a structure that contains an array of ints containing individual data values (one per int)
typedef struct {
    int * values; // a pointer to an array of ints containing values for bit fields    (one per element)
    int n; // the number of elements in the array
} unpacked;


packed pack(sizes s, unpacked un);
unpacked unpack(sizes s, packed p);


#endif
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [.obj : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x6592](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16373522/obj-fatal-error-lnk1107-invalid-or-corrupt-file-cannot-read-at-0x6592)

Comment: You need to delete your object files and do a complete recompile to recreate them.

Comment: [LNK1107](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h6ctxtk.aspx)